# Supporting timezones in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I added a calendar to my rails application. We have events with a start date and an end date (both includes hours and minutes). This ones are fields in the events table, actually their format is datetime. When you select the start date, end date, title and description (among others) for an specific event the the parameters hash is something like this:

```
parameters = {"event" => {"title" => "a title", "description" => "a description", "start_date" => "2012-09-23 23:45", "end_date" => "2012-09-24 15:32"}}
```

In the events controller i have something like this:

```
Event.create(:title => params[:event][:title],
             :description => params[:event][:description],
             :start_date => params[:event][:start_date].present? ? DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:start_date], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") : nil,
             :end_date => params[:event][:end_date].present? ? DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:end_date], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") : nil,
             ...
            )
```

Well, when this event is stored into the database (mysql) the value for start date is "2012-09-23 20:45" while the value for end date is "2012-09-24 12:32". I understand that Rails is automatically dealing with timezones. My problem is that when I want to fetch all the events for a specific time (for example, all events that occurs today) I do:

```
query = "((start_date between ? AND ?) OR (end_date between ? AND ?))"
query << "title NOT LIKE ? AND ..."
self.events.where(query, 
                  Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day, 
                  Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day, 
                  some_restriction_here, ...)
```

I get the wrong events! (it is obvious why, the date and time is different in the database from the inputs). There's and obvious solution also, bring all the events into memory and the date and time will be as the original again but this is expensive in terms of resources. By the other hand this don't solve the problem of timezones, if someone in china crate an event the value in the database will be relative to the time offset of the server localization. I could have a field somewhere where the user can set a time zone and work with this storing a specific date for such user and working through this, what is your suggestion about the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails stores all dates in database in the UTC format. So one way is to always do operations in UTC and in the view convert the displayed dates to current time zone. The other way is to change Rails timezone on the beginning of every action. All parsed times and dates will then be in your custom time zone.

```
def action_name
  Time.zone = "Prague"
  # ... logic
end
```

Comment: ajam, sounds good but not very suitable for my problem, I could have a lot of users connecting from any part of the world and I will need to match any localization to the timezone, moreover, a single entity can be connecting from different locations, anyway thank you very much! .. another thing, how can I tell Rails to don't store it in utc but just as the string I'm passing? I mean, in my case it should store 2012-09-23 23:45 for the start date, don't change it to match the utc time but store just the same string.

Comment: Check out Google Calendar for inspiration. You have your time zone stored in the calendar settings and each event is given this default time zone unless you change it. In my real life experience, when dealing with foreign partners and customers and we are arranging a meeting (or phone call), we always decide on time and timezone (if they are not in my timezone). This I store in my calendar event. Calender than shows me time of this event in for my timezone. You can store date as string. You have to change database column type to do this, but you will loose the ability to do date/time queries.